# Create/Login User from a mobile device using Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle

Tags: android, bundle, symfony

Firstly, I want to create a user sending a post-request from my android app to the server, which uses Symfony2 and the FOSUserBundle.

Finally, I want to login a user from the mobile app and then communicate data with the server.

I know how to implement a post-request on the android-device. But I don't know how I need to configure the FOSUserBundle and security.yml etc to fit my needs. Although I might need a _csrf_token or something and I dont know where to get it from.

I already changed the authentication method from form_login to http_basic and think that this will be the easiest way of doing the authentication (using https to secure the passwords).

But now.. what do I need to do, to achieve the creating and logging in actions without forms? What do I need to put in the post-request on the mobile device?

Thanks for any ideas, comments and solutions!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but I found **the solution**  for registration : (the user enter the username , email and password)

1. In the UserController of your UserBundle  (*src/Project/UserBundle/Controller/DefaultController*)
   define a new function **registerAction()**:

   ```
    public function registerAction()
   {
       $user = new User();

       $request  = $this->getRequest();
       $username = $request->request->get('username');
       $password= $request->request->get('password');
       $email= $request->request->get('email');

     $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory'); 

     $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user); 
     $password = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt()); 
     $user->setPassword($password); 


       $user->setUsername($username);
       $user->setUsernameCanonical($username);
       $user->setEmail($email);
       $user->setEmailCanonical($email);
       $user->setEnabled(true);
       $user->setLocked(false);
       $user->setExpired(false);

       $user->setCredentialsExpired(false);
       $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
       $em->persist($user);
       $em->flush();
      /* $response = new Response(json_encode(array('user' => $tes)));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

         return $response;*/
         return new JsonResponse('good');
   }
   ```

   }

and don't forgot to import :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder;
use Telifoon\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

1. in **UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml** add follwoing route:

   inscription_post:
           pattern:  /v1/api/register
           defaults: { _controller: ProjectUserBundle:Default:register }
           requirements:
               _method:  POST
2. My entity ( ***src/Project/UserBUndle/Entity/User***)  is :

   ```
   use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

   /**
    * User
    */
   class User extends BaseUser
   {
       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           // your own logic
       }
   }
   ```
3. If test the user is added correctely to my database :)

Answer (score 3):

A late answer, but it might help.
I'm working on a similar situation and I got this:

In security.yml

```
security:
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
      id: fos_user.user_manager

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        stateless: true
        http_basic:
            realm: "API"

access_control:
    - { path: /, role: ROLE_USER }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_OWNER:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

In config.yml:

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: <your user class>
```

In my test-method:
Reference: [Authentication for a Symfony2 api (for mobile app use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752250/authentication-for-a-symfony2-api-for-mobile-app-use)

```
public function testAuthentication() 
{
    $client = $this->createClient();

    // not authenticated
    $client->request('GET', '<url>');
    $this->assertEquals(401, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

    // authenticated
    $client->request('GET', '<url>', array(), array(), array(
        'PHP_AUTH_USER' => '<username from your database>', 
        'PHP_AUTH_PW' => '<password>'
    ));
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

}

For communication with that API, I'd suggest [cURL](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz)

Hope this helps!

Cheers,

Dieter